# HTML, CSS. Как отключить input в одном из дочерних элементов checkbox

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox

Доброго времени суток!

Можно ли без скрипта сделать, чтобы при нажатии на зелёный элемент не срабатывал input checkbox'а? В примере наглядно вопрос изложен. 
В интернетах ничего по этому вопросу не нашёл, выручите пожалуйста.

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
  li ul li {
    background: green;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="btn_menu">
     <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form4" />
     <label for="spinner-form4" class="btn_menu_img_on">
      <ul class="box_menu">
       <li>Текст 
        <ul><li>При нажатии сюда - не должен срабатывать input в checkbox</li></ul>
       </li>
       <li>Текст</li>
      </ul>
     </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем - то не сложно:

```js
document.querySelector('.disabled').addEventListener('click',(event)=> {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.box_menu {
  user-select: none;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li ul li {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
    <div class="btn_menu">
     <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form4" />
     <label for="spinner-form4" class="btn_menu_img_on">
      <ul class="box_menu">
       <li>Текст 
        <ul>
              <li class='disabled'>При нажатии сюда - не должен срабатывать input в                       checkbox</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Текст</li>
      </ul>
     </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Как понимаю, только с помощью CSS эту задачу не победить. Спасибо!

Comment: К сожалению нет, по причине всплытия события. Я пробовал ```user select: none```, но в этой ситуации он не помогает. Предлагаю все же ознакомиться с этим свойством.

Answer (score 0):

Я суть вопроса не понял это подойдет

```
<input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form4" disabled/>
```

Comment: Нет, это полностью отключает input.
Я подредактировал вопрос. Там зелёным обозначена область, при нажатии на которую не должна появляться / убираться галочка в checkbox.